# Need to change font-size on one section of website

Tags: html, css

I need to change one section of a webpage.  In this particular section I want the text to be a smaller font size.  For some reason it isn't working.  Below is the html code.  Thanks in advance for your help!

```
Here is my jfiddle:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nmrollagal/GcR9s/

The area that I want to have a smaller font is in the second column after you scroll down and starting where it says Education and Training.

Comment: You don't have <h4> anywhere in your HTML, so where do you want font to be 12px?

Comment: Please do a better job of formatting your question. As it stands, it is very difficult to read and comprehend.

Comment: oh, <h4> is supposed to be where <h3> is.  I just changed that, but I didn't edit it.  Sorry

Comment: I didn't know how to format it.  That was the best I could do.  I just started using this site.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I believe changing it from 11.4px to 11.6px, depending on the font you're using wont make a visible difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the font-size to less than 100% on any parent element to reduce all of text that it contains.
If you want to reduce the font in the "Education and training" section to 90%:

```
dl{
    font-size:90%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the font size for your `<dl>`, you can simply select it in your CSS with `#main dl` and set the `font-size` to whatever you require.

e.g. `#main dl {font-size: 10px}`